# How does the is_slippery parameter affect the reward in Frozenlake Environment?

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-gym, q-learning

How does the is_slippery parameter affect the reward in Frozenlake Environment?

Frozenlake environment has a parameter named is_slippery, which if set to True will move in intended direction with probability of 1/3 else will move in either perpendicular direction with equal probability of 1/3 in both directions. How does this is_slippery parameter affect the reward generated from the environment? Or does it merely do the job of deflecting the agent from it intended path?

Answer (score 0):

The "is_slippery" parameter determines if you are using the Frozenlake environment as stochastic (True) or deterministic (False).

> However, the Frozen Lake environment can also be used in deterministic
> mode. By setting the property is_slippery=False when creating the
> environment, the slippery surface is turned off and then the
> environment always executes the action chosen by the agent.

https://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs470/materials/hws/hw7/FrozenLake.html